# Why there are some files that occasionally replicated themselves in vscode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css, vscode-extensions

In vscode, when I'm working with NodeJS, there are some files that occasionally replicated themselves. Why? and how can I fix it?

[image]

I don't know how to solve..

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the names of the files you can see that they differ by an additional number. This is an indication that you copied such a file in place (for example using copy + paste). Try it out. Select one, say `main.hbs` press  Ctrl+C and then Ctrl+V. You will get a new file named `main 3.hbs` (because `main 2.hbs` already exists.

So, I assume you have done this by accident before, when you believed the code editor has the focus, but instead the file tree was active.